# Configure smtp for Symfony 3 project at platform.sh

Tags: php, symfony, smtp

I try to configure SMTP for my Symfony 3 project on platform.sh but I didn't get it working.

I followed this documentation [https://docs.platform.sh/administration/web/email.html#sending-e-mail][1].

I can't edit parameters.yml because it is generated during build process. So I tried to edit paramters.yml.dist. And updatet it with this code:

```
mailer_transport:  smtp
mailer_host:       "%env(PLATFORM_SMTP_HOST)%"
mailer_user:       null
mailer_password:   null
```

When I do so I will get the following error message during build:

```
W:   [RuntimeException]                                                               
W:   An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:        
W:                                                                                    
W:     [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]    
W:     You have requested a non-existent parameter "env(platform_smtp_host)".
```

So I tried to edit paramters_platform.php and added the following code:

```
$container->setParameter('mailer_host','%env(PLATFORM_SMTP_HOST)%');
```

Then the build process will work but I get the following error message when loading the Website:

```
ParameterNotFoundException in ParameterBag.php line 84:
You have requested a non-existent parameter "env(platform_smtp_host)".
in ParameterBag.php line 84
at ParameterBag->get('env(platform_smtp_host)') in ParameterBag.php line 200
at ParameterBag->resolveString('%env(PLATFORM_SMTP_HOST)%', array('mailer_host' => true, 'env(platform_smtp_host)' => true)) in ParameterBag.php line 171
at ParameterBag->resolveValue('%env(PLATFORM_SMTP_HOST)%', array('mailer_host' => true)) in ParameterBag.php line 200
at ParameterBag->resolveString('%mailer_host%', array('mailer_host' => true)) in ParameterBag.php line 171
at ParameterBag->resolveValue('%mailer_host%', array()) in ParameterBag.php line 161
at ParameterBag->resolveValue(array('transport' => '%mailer_transport%', 'host' => '%mailer_host%', 'username' => '%mailer_user%', 'password' => '%mailer_password%'), array()) in ParameterBag.php line 161
at ParameterBag->resolveValue(array(array('transport' => '%mailer_transport%', 'host' => '%mailer_host%', 'username' => '%mailer_user%', 'password' => '%mailer_password%'))) in MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php line 45
at MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php line 39
at MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in Compiler.php line 104
at Compiler->compile(object(ContainerBuilder)) in ContainerBuilder.php line 597
at ContainerBuilder->compile() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2687
at Kernel->initializeContainer() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2465
at Kernel->boot() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2496
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in app_dev.php line 30
```

Did anyone managed to get SMTP working on plaform.sh? Or does anyone have an idea how to get rid of this problem?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using old Symfony 3x version. `%env()%` syntax was introduced in 3.2 version. As a workaround you can create `parameters.php` file in the configuration directory and import it in `config.yml`. Inside this file just set required container parameters using `getenv()` php function:

```
<?php

$container->setParameter('mailer_host', getenv('PLATFORM_SMTP_HOST'));
```

Some articles:

Setting up external parameters: http://symfony.com/doc/3.3/configuration/external_parameters.html
getenv(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php

Comment: Using this to set a few parameters on the container for a 2.8 project and always worked well.